# Sending Message from Remote Service to Activity via messenger Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, ipc

```
package com.example.huzaifah.ipc;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int MSG_SAY_HELLO2 = 1;
    boolean isBound = false;
    Messenger mMessenger;

    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)        {
            isBound = true;

            // Create the Messenger object
            mMessenger = new Messenger(service);

            // Create a Message
            // Note the usage of MSG_SAY_HELLO as the what value
            Message msg = Message.obtain(null, myservice.MSG_SAY_HELLO, 0,   0);

            // Create a bundle with the data
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("hello", "world");

            // Set the bundle data to the Message

            msg.setData(bundle);

            msg.replyTo=mMessenger2;

            // Send the Message to the Service (in another process)
           try {
                mMessenger.send(msg);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // unbind or process might have crashes
        mMessenger = null;
        isBound = false;
    }
};

//FOR RECIEVING FROM SERVICE////////////////////////////

Messenger mMessenger2 = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler2());

// Incoming messages Handler
class IncomingHandler2 extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_SAY_HELLO2:
                Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                String please = (String) bundle.get("please");

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////

              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, please,     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }

    }
}



//////////////////////////////////////////




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, myservice.class);
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);


}
}





public class myservice extends Service {

private String TAG = "MessengerService";

// Message codes to check against Message.what
//
// Message.what is a User-defined message code so
// that the recipient can identify what the message is about.
static final int MSG_SAY_HELLO = 1;

// Messenger object used by clients to send messages to IncomingHandler
Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
Messenger mess;


// Incoming messages Handler
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_SAY_HELLO:
                Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                String hello = (String) bundle.get("hello");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hello, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                //////////////////////////////////////////////////

                mess = msg.replyTo; //retrieves messenger from the message

                Message m = new Message();                  //create the   message to send back to the client
                Bundle b = new Bundle();                    //Just to show how to send other objects with it
                b.putString("please", "Sent from service"); //this could be any parceable object

                m.setData(b);                               //adds the bundle to the message
                                               //sends message

                try {
                    mess.send(m);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////

                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }

    }
}

public myservice() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
}

/*
Return our Messenger interface for sending messages to
the service by the clients.
*/
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBind done");
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
     return false;
 }

}
```

I am trying to send message from service to activity and vice vers.
Message is sent from Activity to Service but NOT from Service to Activity.

`service` is in a different process and i want to communicate between `service` and `Mainactivity`

```
<service android:name=".myservice" android:process=":myprocess" android:stopWithTask="false" android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: You gave 3 different sets of requirements-  remote service to activity in the question, both ways in your text, then activity to service in your text.  Decide what you want.  And assuming you actually mean a remote service and not an in app service, you'll end up needing to use AIDL.

Comment: service is in a different process and i want to communicate between sevice and Mianactivity.

Comment: <service android:name=".myservice"
            android:process=":myprocess"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:exported="true" />